# Continuous version of the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Does the existence of continuous injections $f: A\rightarrow B$ and $g: B\rightarrow A$ imply the existence of a bicontinuous bijection between A and B (ie topological equivalence)? If not, what is a good counter example?

Comment: That is not a duplicate *per se*, but actually it has a stronger assumption, and the answer is still no.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. $[0,1]$ injects continuously into its subset $(0,1)$ (say, by means of a linear map), but they're not homeomorphic (e.g., think about connectedness after deleting a point).

Answer (score 3):

Another counterexample is the middle-thirds Cantor set $C$ and $X=C\setminus\{0\}$: clearly $X$ embeds in $C$, and it's well-known (and not hard to prove) that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb N\times C$, where $\Bbb N$ has the discrete topology, so $C$ embeds in $X$. However, $C$ is compact, and $X$ is not, so $C$ and $X$ are not homeomorphic.